# how to syncronize cordova and android studio for debugging?

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I have latest version of android studio and android sdk, but I always get gradle version error
commnad: "cordova run android"
so I can't run on device but I can run it on android studio with gradle updating.
what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should delete node-modules folder first and rebuild node-modules using packages.json file

```
{
  "name": "Your app name",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Renelco FSE for Android 6.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "platforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android@6.0.1"
  ],
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-camera@1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-contacts@1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file@2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-media@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration@1.2.0",
    "com.ionic.keyboard@1.0.5"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.4.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.3.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-shell": "~0.6.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {}


}
```